# After the 20.04 update my Search Your Computer always shows "Sorry there is nothing that matches your search."

Tags: upgrade

After the 20.04 update my search computer always shows "Sorry there is nothing that matches your search"
Also my Chromium started locking up and slowed down intermittently. The next time I started the computer the icon was gone and I had to restart it from the terminal window. My Software Center Icon is also gone but I do not know the correct name to start that from the terminal window.
I tried the suggestions I saw in the thread about install ubuntu unity desktop but got a message that it could not open lock file, permission denied.